Unable to do simple HTTPs download
I'm running some dbt spark POC and while doing so discovered it can't pull dependencies. To diagnose the problem I wrote a basic program that downloads the dependency. To my dismay, it isn't working.
But going to the url in my browser works. And curling for the file works:
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12/1.5.2/iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12-1.5.2.pom -O
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5911  100  5911    0     0  56927      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 57388

By why does java, specifically fail? I can see the Global Sign CA in my mac OS keychain Access.
Diagnostic Program:
String fileUrl = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12/1.5.2/iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12-1.5.2.pom";
String outputFilePath = "iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12-1.5.2.pom";

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
    .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(fileUrl))
    .GET()
    .build();

try {
    HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());

    if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
        Files.write(Paths.get(outputFilePath), response.body(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        System.out.println("File downloaded successfully: " + outputFilePath);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to download file. HTTP status code: " + response.statusCode());
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Output:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:956)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:133)
    at com.zscaler.zfabric.management.services.Main.main(Main.java:98)

To make Java use my system's CAs I use:
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore"

I also tried finding the Global Sign CA in my keychain access, exporting it, and importing it into the JDK cacerts and not doing export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Still, it doesn't work.
What could be going wrong?

Are you sure that you run a recent version of Java? You could add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to your JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to get more infos about the problem. How do you run your program, does that way take JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS into account at all?

@cyberbrain+ (1) GlobalSign R3 has been in cacerts of Sun/Oracle builds since at least 6u17 (oldest I have on a still-accessible image) -- but keytool -import would give a warning if you try to import a duplicate. OP: is this an Oracle build or something else? did you use keytool and did you get the correct GlobalSign root (R3)? (GlobalSign has two dozen roots (not all in ccadb) and almost 100 intermediates.) ...

(2) since 11 (and 8u261, but this clearly isn't 8) javax.net.debug=ssl isn't enough to get useful logging; you must add categories like =ssl:handshake:trustmanager. But the only useful thing it will show is the received cert chain, and you can look at that more quickly by keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port]
